# ImageOps.fit is blurring my image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm using ImageOps to resize and center-crop uploaded avatar images. The problem is, when I try to upload an image that is already the desired size, the uploaded image is blurred.

The relevant code:

```
avatar_size = (59,59)
#resized_im = im.resize(avatar_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)   #This works! But doesn't crop.
formatted_im = ImageOps.fit(im, avatar_size, Image.ANTIALIAS, centering=(0.5,0.5))     
formatted_im.save('foo.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=95)
```

So, when I upload a 59x59px image, the resulting upload on the server is blurred. Tried googling, reading the docs, and experimenting, but can't figure this out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably the antialiasing which is causing the blur.
How about try:

```
avatar_size = (59,59)
method = Image.NEAREST if im.size == avatar_size else Image.ANTIALIAS
formatted_im = ImageOps.fit(im, avatar_size, method = method, centering = (0.5,0.5)) 
formatted_im.save('foo.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=95)
```

Comment: What does ANTIALIAS do? couldnt find anything on the documentation